# Ruby's find method - argument?

Tags: ruby, find, arguments

I'm doing a bit of exploring. Concerning Ruby's

```
.find(ifnone = nil) { |obj| block }
```

method: from reading the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find), it seems to me that you are supposed to be able to pass a method as an argument that will be run in the case that there are no matches for the specified conditions.

It says:

> "calls *ifnone* and returns its result when it is specified, or returns
>   `nil` otherwise."

This seems to work with any method I create that already returns nil, say:

```
 
def message
 puts 'No match.'
end
```

```
No match.
=>nil
```

If I use a method that does return something, say:

```
def message
 p 'No match.'
end
```

I'll get:

```
"No match."
NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for "No match.":String
```

Would someone be kind enough to explain to me precisely what kind of arg/method is actually supposed to be passed to the find method here? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm glad you asked this question. I never thought about that argument for the `find` method because I never really had to use it before. I instead always ignored it until you mentioned it here.

The argument you would pass to an enumerable, like `find`, would be a lambda or proc. Rather than returning the default `nil` if no matches were found, it would return the lambda/proc.

So a quick example:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
nums.find(lambda {raise ArgumentError, "No matches found"}) { |num| num == 5 }

> ArgumentError: No matches found
```

Also similarly, you can pass a Proc as well..

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arg = Proc.new {"No matches found"}
nums.find(arg) { |num| num == 5 }

> "No matches found"
```

Just a quick edit, you can return any value in the lambda or proc, whether it be raising an error or returning a value. I imagine raising an error and error handling is a common use though

Edit2: Removed link to an article explaining this method. Seems the blog post has been removed :(

Comment: I was tempted to ignore that argument too. Glad we both learned something! I remember seeing that linked article a while back, but couldn't find it again. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for "No match.":String
> ```

This is a big hint. `find` wants a callable object - i.e. something that responds to `#call`. Since Ruby is duck-typed, all of these will work:

```
def message_method
  puts "yo"
end
...find(method(:message_method)) { ... }

module MessageModule
  def self.call
    puts "yo"
  end
end
...find(MessageModule) { ... }

class MessageClass
  def call
    puts "yo"
  end
end
...find(MessageClass.new) { ... }

message_proc = Proc.new { puts "yo" }
...find(message_proc) { ... }
```

(`lambda` is another way of constructing a `Proc` object; the different syntax makes for a bit different semantics, but the point is `lambda` would work just as well.)

And a perverse example (obsolete):

```
require 'continuation'
callcc do |notfound|
  ...find(notfound) { ... }
  ...
end
```

Comment: While this seems thorough, I understand it less. I think I am just not advanced enough yet to take full advantage of all the info.

Comment: Haha, sorry. The main thing to take away from this is - it can be anything that has a `call` method. This includes `Proc` and `Method` objects, whose `call` method executes the code they wrap.